# javascript w/ jquery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

im having a problem with my code, i have to make a loop, that each it loops, have to change add a class/change the color of something for just a while. i tried with a for and it didnt work, then i tried  something like a loop using setinterval and it works better but still have something that is not working, it just adds the class/or toggle in that case first 1 element, and then maybe 2, then 3,etc and not 1 by 1 thanks

```
function runp(patron){
  var x = 0;
  var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
     $("#container"+patron[x]).toggle(1).delay(1000).toggle(1).delay(1000);
     if (++x === 20) {
         window.clearInterval(intervalID);
     }
  }, 2000);
}
```

this is what i have: https://jsfiddle.net/dt8kxebg/
and this is what im trying to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/jf0opams/

Comment: sry, i edited main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you execute the runp() several times, because it is inside of a for loop. You should rather invoke the function just once after the loop, when your `patron[]` array is filled with random numbers (1-4).

The problem happens, because the for loop is super fast (few millisecs) filling your array with 20 random numbers. So you have invoked the animation/toggling function 20 times. This on/off behaviour takes 2 seconds and happens 20 times almost at the same time. You can see in my code in the browser console what the `console.log()` output to understand the behaviour better.

```
function start(patron, patronl){    
  while (patron.length<20){
    patron.push(rand(1,4));
    console.log('start: '+patron.length);
    //runp(patron, patron.length);//old place
    //readp(patron,//
  }   
  runp(patron);//new place
}

function runp(patron, iteration){
  var x = 0;
  var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
     $("#container"+patron[x]).toggle(1).delay(1000).toggle(1).delay(1000);

     //see how 20 outputs come at once, if runp() is inside for loop
     console.log('togglewait: '+x, 'start: '+iteration);       

     if (++x === 20) {
         window.clearInterval(intervalID);
     }
  }, 2000);
}
```